# Angular 5 All custom javascript after <router-outlet></router-outlet> dont work

Tags: angular

Hello and thank you in advance for your help, 
I added external libraries to my project in index.html
like this :

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js" defer></script>
<script src="assets/js/functions.js" defer></script>
```

with defer all work perfectly in index.html and app.component.html

but after router-outlet
I no longer have any interactions with javascript

Has someone already had this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: add both the libraries in scipts array of angular-cli.json

Comment: What Asad said, and run ng serve again

Comment: thank you for your feedback I have already tried this method but it does not work. I have to delete the markup script in my html? I will try again

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is essentially a problem of angular comprehension, I think that my javascript is loaded before my component. The easiest way would be to make it clear to angular that I want it to load for javascript once the dom completely loaded .. apparently defer is not enough